# @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.analytica.pojo.Client_Unit.city_id references an unknown entity: com.analytica.pojo.CityMaster error

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to insert the data to a table. I am getting the error as

```
31456 [http-bio-8080-exec-7] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.search.HibernateSearchEventListenerRegister - Unable to find org.hibernate.search.event.FullTextIndexEventListener on the classpath. Hibernate Search is not enabled.
31457 [http-bio-8080-exec-7] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - Binding entity from annotated class: com.analytica.pojo.Client_Unit
31457 [http-bio-8080-exec-7] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Bind entity com.analytica.pojo.Client_Unit on table cu_client_unit
@OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.analytica.pojo.Client_Unit.city_id references an unknown entity: com.analytica.pojo.CityMaster
error
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.analytica.pojo.Client_Unit.city_id references an unknown entity: com.analytica.pojo.CityMaster

Unit
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="CU_CM_ID")
public CityMaster getCity_id() {
return city_id;
}
public void setCity_id(CityMaster city_id) {
this.city_id = city_id;
}

City
@Id
@Column(name="CM_ID")
@OneToMany
public int getCity_id() {
return city_id;
}
public void setCity_id(int city_id) {
this.city_id = city_id;
}
```

I am trying to insert the values to db. I am getting the error as @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.analytica.pojo.Client_Unit.city_id references an unknown entity: com.analytica.pojo.CityMaster
error

Comment: Show your code please (Client_Unitof Unit and CityMaster). Then we can try to help you.

Comment: I have added the code.. Please check..

Comment: I think the mappedBy attribute is missing on OneToMany

Comment: I even tried mapped by.. But it isn't working

Answer (score 0):

In an unidirectional OneToMany scenario, you just need to annotate the parent class.

```
@Entity
public class Unit{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private int id;

  //getter and setter
}    

@Entity   
public class CityMaster{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private int id;

  @OneToMany
  @JoinColumn(name = "CU_ID")
  Set<Unit> units = new Hashmap<>();     

   //getter and setter 
 }
```

Comment: Nope... City is my parent class and unit is the referencing class.. How can i change main class id to child class?